# How write non blocking code in nodejs and what I am doing wrong?

Tags: node.js

I have a route named pdf and if I go to the route it waits 10 sec because I create a pdf and other things. But if I go to other screen and the pdf route is not finish yet then my other response waiting and I can not use the site until pdf route is finish. How can I not block the response ?

PDFCreate file

```
var pdf = require("pdf-creator-node");
const path = require('path');
import fs from 'fs-extra';

export default async function PDFCreate() {
  try {
    var options = {
      format: "A3",
      orientation: "portrait",
      border: "10mm",
      header: {
          height: "0mm",
      },
      footer: {
          height: "28mm",
          contents: {
              first: 'Cover page',
              2: 'Second page', // Any page number is working. 1-based index
              default: '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>', // fallback value
              last: 'Last Page'
          }
      }
  };
    console.log(path.join(__dirname));
    const html = fs.readFileSync('app/data/file.html', 'utf-8');
    const bitmap = fs.readFileSync('public/images/lg.jpeg');
    const logo = bitmap.toString('base64');
    const filename = Math.random() + '_doc' + '.pdf';

    const document = {
      html: html,
      data: {
        logo
      },
      path: './docs/' + filename
  }

    pdf.create(document, options)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    const filepath = 'http://localhost:3000/public/images/' + filename;

    return filepath;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

/PDF route (I use fullstack framework so the loader is equivalent with this: route.get('/s', (res, req)'))

```
import PDFCreate from '~/data/createPDF.server'

export default async function loader() {
  try {
    await PDFCreate();
    return null;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

/home

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main className="container test">
        <p>test</p>
      </main>
    </>
  )
};
```

So when I call /pdf and its loading and if I go to home route then my home route loads until /pdf is finish... how can I not block this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make use of `abort` the `PDFCreate()` execution on unmounting of `loader` component using `AbortController`.
For Example -

- Firstly wrap the function code to `promise` and register callback for `abort` event.
  PDFCreate file

  ```
    var pdf = require("pdf-creator-node");
        const path = require("path");
        import fs from "fs-extra";

            export default async function PDFCreate(abortSignal) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    // Wrap to promise

                    // register abort event
                    abortSignal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
                        // 6
                        const error = new DOMException(
                    "Calculation aborted by the user",
                    "AbortError"
                );
                reject(error); // 8
            });

            try {
                var options = {
                    format: "A3",
                    orientation: "portrait",
                    border: "10mm",
                    header: {
                        height: "0mm",
                    },
                    footer: {
                        height: "28mm",
                        contents: {
                            first: "Cover page",
                            2: "Second page", // Any page number is working. 1-based index
                            default:
                                '<span style="color: #444;">{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>', // fallback value
                            last: "Last Page",
                        },
                    },
                };
                console.log(path.join(__dirname));
                const html = fs.readFileSync("app/data/file.html", "utf-8");
                const bitmap = fs.readFileSync("public/images/lg.jpeg");
                const logo = bitmap.toString("base64");
                const filename = Math.random() + "_doc" + ".pdf";

                const document = {
                    html: html,
                    data: {
                        logo,
                    },
                    path: "./docs/" + filename,
                };

                pdf
                    .create(document, options)
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res);
                        resolve(); // Resolve on success
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

                const filepath = "http://localhost:3000/public/images/" + filename;
                return filepath;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                throw e;
            }
        });
      }
  ```
- Now initiate `abortController` in `loader` component and pass the `abortController` while calling `PDFCreate()` function.
  Call `abortController.abort()` on unmounting of `loader` component, maybe here you can use framework-specific component life-cycle method that.
  /PDF route

import PDFCreate from "~/data/createPDF.server";

```
export default async function loader() {
    let abortController = null;

    // Call abortController.abort when loader() component unmounts
    if (abortController) abortController.abort();

    try {
        abortController = new AbortController();
        await PDFCreate(abortController);
        return null;
    } catch (e) {
        abortController = null;
        console.log(e);
    }
  }
```